# Linear transformation and eigens

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi guys I need some help understanding how find Eigenvectors for the following problem.

Define $T \in \mathscr{L}(F^2)$ by $T(w,z) = (z,w)$

So I set up the problem like so...

$z=\lambda w $

$w=\lambda z$

I see its obvious that when you substitute you obtain:

$w=\lambda z = \lambda (\lambda w)=\lambda^2w$

$\implies \lambda = \pm 1$

How do I find the corresponding Eigenvectors with those values? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(w,z)$ is a vector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, then

$$(z,w) = T(w,z) = 1(w,z) = (w,z)$$

so that $w = z$. It follows that all eigenvectors are of the form $(w,w)$.

---

On the other hand, an identical computation for the eigenvalue $-1$ leads to a similar relationship between $w$ and $z$, just with a minus sign involved.

Comment: So would the Eigenvector for $\lambda =-1$ would be $(-w,-w)$?

Comment: @STuDuNt Not quite. You should find the relationship $(z,w) = (-w,-z)$, so that $z = -w$.

Comment: hmm (w,-w)? Would that make it right?

Comment: @STuDuNt Yes, that's the right result.